# Database design / data model for socail networking

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, erd

I am designing a database for a social media website (uni assignment). 
I have been struggling with the **messages** link to **member**. There will be a need for two foreign keys from the same primary key in messages. One for the sending member and one for the receiving member. I was unsure if this was possible or a good idea so i was thinking of assign a member to a inbox (Many Members - One Inbox). Then assign all messages to the inbox (One Inbox - Many Messages).

Member **Many**------**1** Inbox **1**------**Many** Messages

Tables look like....

##################

**Member Profiles**
Member ID (PK)
Name
Gender
Inbox ID (FK)

##################

**Inbox**
Inbox ID

##################

**Message**
Message ID (PK)
Inbox ID (FK)
Message Direction .... *either to or from (then the members name)*
Member ID (FK)

That's what Ive got so far id appreciate some pointers if ive gone off the right path. Because the more i look at my design the less i like it.

Comment: dont have a high enough rep to post an image as yet

Comment: Why does a member have many inboxes?

Comment: its many member have only one inbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No don't do that

Messages can belong to multiple members and members can have mulitple messages, so you need what is called a Join table.

```
MemberMessage
Memberid
Message id
```

Comment: I originally thought of this but went completely off track with the though of using an inbox to solve my issue of sender and receiver two Member IDs in one table.

Comment: Im still a little confused on when displaying a query result say i wanted to search all the messages "joe bloggs" has "sent". would that table design be able to give me ... member name of sender,Member name of receiver, message contents etc... OR doesnt it matter? Am i thinking up problems that aint there?

Comment: @FunksterPhillipWatkins you can easily get the data with a join statement.

Comment: OK Thanks. So what i was thinking was 3 tables Members, MemberMessage and Messages. Member has MemberID and other attributes.##### Membermessage has composite Primary Key of MessageID, SenderID(memberID) and  ReceiverID(also memberID).###### Message has MessageID, Message content, etc. Would that be okay?

Comment: You would be better off with MemeberId, messageId, messagedirection where you put sent or recieved in that last field. You don;t want to have to join twice to get all teh messages for one user

Comment: With only one MemberID how would you know which 2 members the message is linked?

Comment: By querying on the message id

Comment: After all messages may well go to several people too

Comment: Sorry, Im still struggling with how the message is recorded. Say a record is MemberID="1", MessageID= "1", MessageDirection="Sent", MessageContent="Hello!" ..... I can see that member 1 has sent the message but how do we know who receives it? Sorry again, I just want to get my head around this method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The draft model may helps you:
**Message creation**:
[image]

**Message consumption:** (after send message process)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing the MemberID field on the Message table to something like SendingMemberID, and then adding another field called ReceivingMemberID?  This would allow you to avoid the somewhat confusing Message Direction field.

Sure you'd need to join to it twice to get all incoming and outgoing messages for a user, but that's really not a bad thing.  The alternative option of having two records for each message (one for sender, one for receiver) has its own drawbacks.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you think i will require a join table in between member and message with the composite primary and foreign SendingMemberID, ReceivingMemberID and MessageID within it?